# To get the SNS Topic name from the SNS Topic ARN using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns

I am writing a boto3 script where I have to list the sns topics by name but the problem is that right now I don't think `get_topic_name()` API is in place and when I tried this `method(function)` I got the error. Right now the output is coming in the form of **arn:aws:{region}:{account_number}:{topic_name}** The output is something like (for e.g. `arn:aws:ca-central-1:111122223333:sns-test-topic`
Can someone tell how to fetch the name only?

This is the code:-

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

account_id = input("Enter the AWS account Id:")
regions = ['ap-northeast-1', 'ap-southeast-1',
       'ca-central-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-east-2']

for region in regions:
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client('sns', region_name=region)
    for arn in client.list_topics()['Topics']:
        print(arn['TopicArn'])
```

Answer (score 2):

As the name of the topic is always the last field of the ARN, you can use rsplit to extract them:

```
print(arn['TopicArn'].rsplit(':',1)[1])
```